# Increase a value if a number in a row changes

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to use `mutate()` to increase a value in a column if a value changes in another row and resets to `1` if a value changes in a third row like the following example:

```
col1 col2 count
0    1    1 
0    1    1
0    2    2
0    3    3
1    4    1
1    5    2
1    5    2
```

The part with changes in `row1` works well but the second part with the changing values in `row2` didn't work. I only get the following results:

```
col1 col2 count
0    1    1 
0    1    2
0    2    3
0    3    4
1    4    1
1    5    2
1    5    3
```

This is my working code:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(col1, col2)%>%
  mutate(counter=row_number())%>%
  ungroup
```

I already tried this:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(col1)%>%
  mutate(counter=row_number())%>%
  group_by(col2)%>%
  mutate(counter= 'failed_code')%>%
  ungroup
```

but using functions like `if_else` or `case_when` didn't work with my given arguments. How could I implement a `counter` for `col2` which increases only if the rows changes and reset to `1` if `col1` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table` you can use `rleid`:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), col2 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,count:=rleid(col2), by = col1]
df
#   col1 col2 count
#1:    0    1     1
#2:    0    1     1
#3:    0    2     2
#4:    0    3     3
#5:    1    4     1
#6:    1    5     2
#7:    1    5     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `consecutive_id` (introduced with `dplyr >= 1.1.0`) you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

dat <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  col2 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
) 

dat |> 
  mutate(count = consecutive_id(col2), .by = col1)
#>   col1 col2 count
#> 1    0    1     1
#> 2    0    1     1
#> 3    0    2     2
#> 4    0    3     3
#> 5    1    4     1
#> 6    1    5     2
#> 7    1    5     2
```